# Look if a folder has some files with certain extensions

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting, ls, wildcards

Suppose I have a file structure:

```
$ cd /home/Desktop
$ ls -d */
Abc/ Qwe/ Zxc/ Rty/
$
```

Now I want to iterate through every directory and see if they have any ".pdf" files. 
 Could some one please tell what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for dir in Abc/ Qwe/ Zxc/ Rty/; do
  result="$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pdf' -printf .)"
  echo "Folder '${dir}' contains ${#result} *.pdf files."
done
```

This ignores subdirectories.

Comment: This works exactly I want it to :D
Thanks Hauke :)

Comment: That assumes GNU `find`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find /home/Desktop -type f -name '*.pdf'`.

Comment: This lists all the PDF files without indicating which toplevel directories contain any. That's like giving someone a cow when they ask for a hamburger.

Comment: Incorrect. This lists all pdf files _with_ directories for each file. So you can easily see which file belongs to which directory.
Yes, it seems author wanted something more like true/false, but i see no way to figure this out from question

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` is certainly the fastest way to do it. If you want to restrict the directories to look for, you can use:

`find <dir1> <dir2> ... -type f -name '*.pdf'`

If you want to count the number of files:

`find <dir1> <dir2> ... -type f -name '*.pdf' | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
for dir (Abc Qwe Zxc Rty) {
  pdf=($dir/*.pdf(ND.))
  print -r "Directory '$dir' contains ${#pdf} *.pdf files"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to do this, depending on what you want to do with the information.

- If you want a list of directories which directly contain `.pdf` files (i.e. only at the top level, not within subdirectories), I'd go with this:

  ```
  dirname */*.pdf | sort | uniq
  ```
- If you want a list of directories which contain `.pdf` files at any level (so they could be within subdirectories of the directory), try

  ```
  find . -name '*.pdf' | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq
  ```

  or, if you want to search only certain subdirectories,

  ```
  find Abc Qwe Zxc Rty -name '*.pdf' | cut -d/ -f1 | sort | uniq
  ```
- If you want a list of all the `.pdf` files within the subdirectories, that's just

  ```
  find . -name '*.pdf'
  ```
- If you want a count of `.pdf` files within each directory, to count only files at the top level I'd use

  ```
  dirname */*.pdf | sort | uniq -c
  ```

  or to include files in subdirectories

  ```
  find . -name '*.pdf' | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c
  ```

  (you can tell the difference is simply adding the `-c` option to `uniq`).